# Search text and append to each end of line of text file - OSX

Tags: macos, bash, text, sed, append

I'm new to OSX command line tools.

I am trying to find a block of text in a file and append this text at the end of all lines in another text file. At run time I don't know what this text will be, I just know it will be located within "BEGINHMM" and "ENDHMM". Also, I don't know the makeup of the destination file, except for that it will not be an empty text file.

The command which finds the block of text of interest is:

```
sed -n '/<BEGINHMM>/,/<ENDHMM>/p' proto
```

where "proto" is a text file containing the text of interest.

I've been trying to pipe the output of the above command to another 'sed' command, in the following manner:

```
xargs -I '{}' sed -i .bak 's/$/{}/' monophones0.txt
```

but I am getting some bizarre results, I see the "{}" inserted in the text for example.

I've also tried piping to:

```
xargs -0 sed -i .bak 's/$/&/' monophones0.txt
```

but I just get the printout (similar to terminal echo) of the text I am trying to grab.

Ultimately I want to loop over several 'proto' files in multiple directories and copy the text between the "BEGINHMM", "ENDHMM" block in each directory, and append the selected text to that directory's monophones.txt lines.

I am running the commands in the terminal, bash, OSX 10.12.2

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't your problem with `xargs` because your approach is wrong (IMO). Using `xargs` plus `sed` with unsanitized input will just land you in a quoting hell. What you should do instead is to save what you need to append in a string, then use a read and write loop. I won't recommend `sed` here.

Comment: But I'm still not sure what command to use to append "dynamic" text to end of lines in a file. Any recommendation what would accomplish this ?

Comment: You are trying to append multiple lines of input to each line of some other file? How is that supposed to work?

Comment: `str_to_append=" tail"; while IFS= read -r line; do printf "%s%s\n" "$line" "$str_to_append"; done <input >output_tmp; mv output_tmp input`.

Comment: I expect the same behavior that I would, if I was to graphically copy & paste the highlighted text at the end of the line. It would create new lines appended at the original end of lines.

Comment: Wait what, you don't need to discard newlines, so you want that block after every line? Then save that block to a tmpfile and `sed 'r tmpfile'`.

Comment: Sorry, but this is very new to me. What would be the syntax for appending the output from 'sed 'r tmpfile' to the existing file ?

Comment: Just like what you did before. `tmpfile=$(mktemp); sed -n '/<BEGINHMM>/,/<ENDHMM>/p' proto >$tmpfile; sed -i .bak "r $tmpfile" monophones0.txt; rm $tmpfile`. This is the basic idea; there are other checks you need to perform to make this a robust script.

Comment: You are a life saver !! Thank you, it works.

Comment: I believe you want to extract the text between `<BEGINHMM>` & `<ENDHMM>`, without these tags included. This awk is a simple one: `awk '/<ENDHMM>/{p=0};p;/<BEGINHMM>/{p=1}'` :  `awk 'NR==FNR && /<ENDHMM>/{p=0};p{a=a$0};NR==FNR && /<BEGINHMM>/{p=1}; NR!=FNR{print $0 a}' proto monophones0.txt > monophones0.txt.new && mv monophones0.txt.new monophones0.txt`

Answer (score 0):

(1) Your sed command is of the form `sed -n '/A/,/B/p'`; this will include the lines on which A and B occur, even if these strings do not appear at the beginning of the line.  This form may have other surprises in store for you as well (what do expect will happen if B is missing or repeated?), but the remainder of this post assumes that's what you want.

(2) It's not clear how you intend to specify the "proto" files, but you do indicate they might be in several directories, so for the remainder of this post, I'll assume they are listed, one per line, in a file named `proto.txt` in each directory.  This will ensure that you don't run into any limitations on command-line length, but the following can easily be modified if you don't want to create such a file.

(3) Here is a script which will use the sed command you've mentioned to copy segments from each of the "proto" files specified in a directory to monophones0.txt in the directory in which the script is executed.

```
#!/bin/bash

OUT=monophones0.txt

cat proto.txt | while read file
do
  if [ -r "$file" ] ; then
    sed -n '/<BEGINHMM>/,/<ENDHMM>/p' "$file" >> $OUT
  elif [ -n "$file" ] ; then
    echo "NOT FOUND: $file" >&2
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like what you did before. `tmpfile=$(mktemp); sed -n '/<BEGINHMM>/,/<ENDHMM>/p' proto >$tmpfile; sed -i .bak "r $tmpfile" monophones0.txt; rm $tmpfile`. This is the basic idea; there are other checks you need to perform to make this a robust script.
                    – 4ae1e1